# How to iterate over an array of JQuery objects and apply a function to each one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a jQuery function I need to run based on how many divs I have in my html. Here is the function I need to run:

```
$('#ChildVerticalTab_1').easyResponsiveTabs({
    type: 'vertical',
    width: 'auto',
    fit: true,
    tabidentify: 'ver_1', // The tab groups identifier
    activetab_bg: '#fff', // background color for active tabs in this group
    inactive_bg: '#F5F5F5', // background color for inactive tabs in this group
    active_border_color: '#c1c1c1', // border color for active tabs heads in this group
    active_content_border_color: '#5AB1D0' // border color for active tabs contect in this group so that it matches the tab head border
});
```

The problem is that I will have an unknown number of "#ChildVerticalTab_" divs so I will need to run the function for #ChildVerticalTab_1, #ChildVerticalTab_2, #ChildVerticalTab_3 etc. etc.

I tried using a loop:

```
var serviceCount = $('.hor_1 div[id^="ChildVerticalTab"]').length;
for(var i = 0; i <= serviceCount; i++) {
    $('#ChildVerticalTab_'+i).easyResponsiveTabs({
        type: 'vertical',
        width: 'auto',
        fit: true,
        tabidentify: 'ver_'+i, // The tab groups identifier
        activetab_bg: '#fff', // background color for active tabs in this group
        inactive_bg: '#F5F5F5', // background color for inactive tabs in this group
        active_border_color: '#c1c1c1', // border color for active tabs heads in this group
        active_content_border_color: '#5AB1D0' // border color for active tabs contect in this group so that it matches the tab head border
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work. In this case, there are five ChildVerticalTab divs. It looks like the above ran the function five times per single div if that makes sense.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="parentHorizontalTab">
   <ul class="resp-tabs-list hor_1">
      <li>Ophthalmology</li>
      <li>Hand/Wrist/Elbow</li>
      <li>Endoscopy/GI</li>
      <li>General Surgery</li>
      <li>Foot/Ankle</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="resp-tabs-container hor_1">
      <div id="ChildVerticalTab_1">
         <ul class="resp-tabs-list ver_1">
            <li>Service Name 1</li>
            <li>Service Name 2</li>
            <li>service Name 3</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="resp-tabs-container ver_1">
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at volutpat. Donec at laoreet ex, ut feugiat velit. Pellentesque in diam ornare, sollicitudin ipsum eget, eleifend lorem. Praesent eget orci eget est fringilla consectetur.</p>
               <p>Code: 123</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at volutpat. Donec at laoreet ex, ut feugiat velit. Pellentesque in diam ornare, s</p>
               <p>Code: 124</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at </p>
               <p>Code: 125</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="ChildVerticalTab_2">
         <ul class="resp-tabs-list ver_2">
            <li>Service Name 1</li>
            <li>Service Name 2</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="resp-tabs-container ver_2">
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla iam ornare, sollicitudin ipsum eget, eleifend lorem. Praesent eget orci eget est fringilla consectetur.</p>
               <p>Code: 126</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at volutpat. Donec at laoreet ex, ut feugiat velit. Pellentesque in diam ornare, sollicitudin ipsum eget, eleifend lorem. Praesent eget orci eget est fringilla consectetur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at volutpat. Donec at laoreet ex, ut feugiat velit. Pellentesque in diam ornare, sollicitudin ipsum eget, eleifend lorem. Praesent eget orci eget est fringilla consectetur.</p>
               <p>Code: 127</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="ChildVerticalTab_3">
         <ul class="resp-tabs-list ver_3">
            <li>Service Name 1</li>
            <li>Service Name 2</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="resp-tabs-container ver_3">
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, copulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at volutpat. Donec at laoreet ex, ut feugiat velit. Pellentesque in diam ornare, sollicitudin ipsum eget, eleifend lorem. Praesent eget orci eget est fringilla consectetur.</p>
               <p>Code: 128</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar  fringilla consectetur.</p>
               <p>Code: 129</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="ChildVerticalTab_4">
         <ul class="resp-tabs-list ver_4">
            <li>Service Name 1</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="resp-tabs-container ver_4">
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at volutpat. Donec at laoreet ex, ut sum eget, eleifend lorem. Praesent eget orci eget est fringilla consectetur.</p>
               <p>Code: 130</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="ChildVerticalTab_5">
         <ul class="resp-tabs-list ver_5">
            <li>Service Name 1</li>
            <li>Service Name 2</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="resp-tabs-container ver_5">
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elementum malesuada. Vestibulum ac ipsum tempus, vehicula nibh ut, consequat nulla. Nulla maximus vulputate ante at vol</p>
               <p>Code: 131</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu accumsan urna. Fusce varius eu dolor et ullamcorper. Cras lacinia nisl vel magna consequat ornare. Ut molestie pulvinar augue elesum eget, eleifend lorem. Praesent eget orci eget est fringilla consectetur.</p>
               <p>Code: 132</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('.hor_1 div[id^="ChildVerticalTab"]').each() so much better than for loop.

Comment: So you need to select them all at the same time? Remove length and use serviceCount.easyReponsivrTabs(...)

Comment: @epascarello Performance wise? I would think the native JS's `for-loop` would reign superior. No?

Comment: @carl edwards, yes vanilla js beats them all.

Comment: because jQuery is not doing a loop inside? lol? Problem here is OP is looking up the DOM every time when each gives the reference.

Comment: @espacarello if i get it right, the OP simply needs to call the function on the whole collection.

Comment: yes, but not really since one of the props is updated

Comment: @Jonasw no because each instance has slightly different option values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery has a each method which runs a function once per Element in the Jquery 
Object.

The individual object can be accessed by `this` in the passed function. which can be wrapped in a jquery method to get the jquery object i.e. `$(this`)

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
  $('.hor_1 div[id^="ChildVerticalTab"]').each(function( index ) {
      $(this).easyResponsiveTabs({
            type: 'vertical',
            width: 'auto',
            fit: true,
            tabidentify: 'ver_'+index, // The tab groups identifier // may need to do index-1 depending on your needs
            activetab_bg: '#fff', // background color for active tabs in this group
            inactive_bg: '#F5F5F5', // background color for inactive tabs in this group
            active_border_color: '#c1c1c1', // border color for active tabs heads in this group
            active_content_border_color: '#5AB1D0' // border color for active tabs contect in this group so that it matches the tab head border
        });
    });
```

Comment: `i` is undefined now

Comment: you are correct i thought i got rid of the need for `i`. answer has been updated

Comment: This isn't working either. I think it's because each "ChildVerticalTab" div also needs to include the number. For example, #ChildVerticalTab_1 #ChildVerticalTab_2 #ChildVerticalTab_3 etc. etc.

Comment: @user715564 no, you do not need the number $(this) is the element and index is the index.

Comment: @user715564 my guess is the original selector is incorrect but you haven't shown the html

Comment: since you have the `div[id^="ChildVerticalTab"]` in the selector it should get them regardless of any suffix

Comment: Only way this would fail is if the numbers are out of order.

Comment: what exactly is the error. is it not running? looping too much?

Comment: i still dont understand what the problem is exactly

Comment: It's hard to explain, here is an image of what is being rendered. http://imgur.com/a/2QRV4

Comment: Actually, it looks like the problem might be with the actual tabs plugin I am using. If I manually write a function for each ChildVerticalTab div, I still get problems. Thanks for the help, I will go ahead and make your answer as correct since it technically is.

Answer (score -3):

How about assigning a marker class to these divs, say .cvt then

```
$('.cvt').easyResponsiveTabs({
    type: 'vertical',
    width: 'auto',
    fit: true,
    tabidentify: 'ver_1', // The tab groups identifier
    activetab_bg: '#fff', // background color for active tabs in this group
    inactive_bg: '#F5F5F5', // background color for inactive tabs in this group
    active_border_color: '#c1c1c1', // border color for active tabs heads in this group
    active_content_border_color: '#5AB1D0' // border color for active tabs contect in this group so that it matches the tab head border
});
```

Comment: This is not instance specific